# Cannot disable option "Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library"

Tags: itunes, mac

I want to disable the preference *"Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library"* in *iTunes Preferences > Advanced*.

However, every time I uncheck the box and click OK, it seems to refuse to disable this feature. The box is checked again if I immediately go back to the screen.

Is there some way to disable this via a plist file? Or should I reinstall iTunes somehow?

---

FYI: I am running iTunes Version 12.9.4.94 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4, on a 2018 Mac Mini restored from a 2011 iMac that ran High Sierra before it died. As I've had my iTunes library running over several years, I'm guessing that there may be some configuration bug somewhere.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be some kind of bug. Only workaround I've found is to also disable "Keep iTunes media folder organized."  When I untick this box, the other seems to stay disabled.  If I try to re-enable it, the "Copy Files..." re-enables as well.  They're linked somehow. Did you have any success deleting itunes plist?

Comment: "Keep files organised" means keep them organised *in the iTunes media folder*.

Comment: Ok - I'm not sure that was ever a question. However, the "Keep iTunes Media folder organized" option has never been linked to the "Copy files to iTunes Media Folder" before... Now, it is impossible to deselect "Copy Files" permanently without also deselecting the "Keep itunes media folder organized". Clearly, some kind of software bug.

Comment: I thought remembered them always being linked like that. I must be mistaken